# How to fit layer correctly in map using leaflet overlay?

Tags: leaflet, gis, qgis

I have implemented the following piece of code where I need to fit a layer over a map, that I made using QGIS. But the coordinates are not working correctly, what should I do? The problem are the wrong coordinates or there is a way to fit the layer in the map correctly using overlay?

[image: This print show the borders that are not fitting]
[image: This print show the same map and layer fitting perfectly in QGIS]

```
var L;

var initialCoordinates = [-14.91, -43.20];
var initialZoomLevel = 4;

// create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
map = L.map('heatmap').setView(initialCoordinates, initialZoomLevel);

L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
});

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
// L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
//   attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
//   maxZoom: 19
// }).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
    attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 18,
    ext: 'png'
}).addTo(map);

// [[5.32, -28.95], [-33.1999, -73.9]]
var imageUrl = '/images/temperatureMapDefault.png', //temperatureMapDefault.png
    imageBounds = [[5.32, -28.95], [-33.1999, -73.9]]; // [[ymin, xmin][ymax, xmax]]
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates for the bounding box are working just fine; the problem is in the projections.

Your QGIS project, and your output image, are using EPSG:4326. Leaflet uses EPSG:3857 (spherical mercator) for display. If you try to overlay a stretched EPSG:4326 image over a EPSG:3957 one, the top and bottom edges will fit but you'll experience a vertical shift.

You can see this more clearly by creating a bigger image in EPSG:4326 with country boundaries. I encourage you to experiment.

Please read https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html and related documentation in order to configure your QGIS project to use a different CRS.

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez, again you're helping me!